# Elasticsearch How to separate data by node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one index but have different type. how to separate the type into different node.
my data insert to elasticsearch 2.4 will be as below:

```
/news/trkd/
/news/ph/
/news/nnr
```

How to separate this folder into different nodes?
For example:

```
/news/trkd/ to node 1,
/news/ph/ to node 2.
/news/nnr to node 3...
```

Thanks and Best regards
Sharon

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If one node goes down or gets corrupted, you'll lose your data.

Comment: Moreover, ES only allows to assign an index to a specific set of nodes but not mapping types.

Comment: ya...i confirm want to do like this...ES only to assign indexs, so can't make types...Ok...